# Problems to startproyect django-admin

Tags: django-admin, environment-variables

i'm trying to start a proyect, and this errors occurs when I made **startproyect** with **django-admin**

```
esteban@esteban-gl:/var/www/django_proyect$ django-admin startproyect ap1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Django==1.8.2', 'console_scripts', 'django-admin')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 182, in fetch_command
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Realy I'm not good using linux, but I was reading that is best work in linux distribution. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04
I don't know how set environment variables here :(

Comment: `startpro**j**ect`, but i'm sure you figured it out by now

Comment: YES @DejaVu Thanks!, I'm a st*pid. I'm argentine, and I mix Poyect with poject.